# Cocos2d game: nothing is visible on real device

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, testflight

I have a Cocos2D game I want to install on my devices with Testflight. For any reason I only see a black screen when I start the project after installing via Testflight. It works fine on the simulator.

Here is the AppDelegate file: http://pastebin.com/KJwqq1us

Here is some of the code of the main menu: http://pastebin.com/9pE1drH1

The strange thing: When I add a viewController's view as a subview I see the view controller, but not the Cocos2d elements.

Would be awesome, if somebody could help me out with that problem :) Thanks in advance!

Edit:
When I install and run the game with Xcode it doesn't work as well. I tried to clean the project, delete the build folder. I create the ipa file by building for archiving -> archive -> use organizer to export as ipa file and upload this file directly to Testflight. Could the startup image cause a problem with the cocos2d layers? When I compile my application, no errors or warning are shown. No matter if I run it on the simulator in retina or non retina, it always works. On any real device it doesn't show anything related to Cocos2d like sprites or the menu

Comment: You haven't really given enough information (ie code) as to what your app is doing. Why are you just installing via TestFlight rather than attaching the device and debugging through XCode so you can see what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the blackscreen by updating the cocos2d framework to the latest beta version. I'm not sure what exactly was causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stab-in-the-dark answer as you haven't given enough details to go on....

Check the case of your graphics files and in your code match. Remember that the device IS case sensitive, but the simulator is NOT.

Comment: It works when I install and the app via Xcode. I don't understand why the whole menu and the game content is not shown. The menu itself doesn't consist out of any graphic files. I added some more information to my original post